# multi-select options escaping characters

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I have a DOM multi-select filter on a single column in a table.  The filter is defined with:

```js
yadcf.init(table, [{
  column_number: 1,
  filter_type: "multi_select",
  select_type: 'select2',
  select_type_options: {theme: 'bootstrap', width: '250px'},
}]);
```

When the select is rendered, then it is escaping characters which appear in the table, such as '>', which means that the filtering does not work.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: please provide a minimal test page on jsfiddle or simialr

Comment: I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewhegarty/jpnxq4sv/4/), however this is not reproducing the issue.  I am using django and the HTML is being rendered correctly with HTML escaping - I think this is why it appears escaped in the 'select'.  The jsFiddle handles the escaping ok, which is not what I'm seeing.

Comment: The workaround is to use the yadcf `data` attribute which renders correctly in the select.

Comment: how about adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your `<head>` tag in html?

Comment: thanks - I already have that

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this by adding:

```
column_data_type: "rendered_html"
```

[yadcf docs](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/18cc2fb1fdc59e2fac954a391aaa7211ebfaa367/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L76)